# How to compute the total variation of a complex measure?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mu =\mu_1 + i \mu_2$. is a complex measure and $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are positive and finite.

What is the total variation $\left|\mu\right|$ in this two cases?

1) $\mu_1 \perp \mu_2$.

2) $\mu_1 = \mu_2 .$

I don't know how to use the decompositions and if it may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints.

In the first case, one can find disjoint sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ whose union is the whole space and such that $\mu_1(B)=0$ for each measurable subset $B$ of $A_2$ and $\mu_2(B)=0$  for each measurable subset $B$ of $A_1$. 
If $B$ is a measurable subset of $A_2$, and if $(C_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a measurable partition of a subset $C$, what can you say about $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|\mu\left(C_n\cap B\right)\right|$? Therefore, what is $\left|\mu\right|\left(B\cap C\right)$?

Then you can similarly compute $\left|\mu\right|\left(B\cap C\right)$ when $B$ is a measurable subset of $A_1$ and then get $\left|\mu\right|\left( C\right)$.

When $\mu_1=\mu_2$, what can you say about $\left|\mu(A)\right|$ for a measurable set $A$? Then use the definition of total variation of a measure to get $\left|\mu\right|$.